# XAML Primitives in WinRT / Win8 Metro

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Has anyone been able to add primitives in XAML in WinRT? I'm trying to run the following, which is standard in all XAML-based technologies except for WinRT:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:System="using:System">

    <System:Double x:Key="MyWidth">550</System:Double>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

This does not show an error in Visual Studio, but it will throw a XamlParseException with a message "The type 'Double' was not found..."

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The namespace for system types have been replaced with 'x'

```
<x:Double>550</x:Double>
```

Comment: Seriously, thank you. It's all of these tiny, stupid, unnecessary changes that make Win8 development frustrating as heck for WPF/Silverlight devs.